# Cocoa variable declaration

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

can someone tell me why there is a * in the line?

What does it mean for the declaration?

```
NSString *someString;
```

Thank you guys

edit:

Thank you it helps me a lot but sometimes i see declarations without * 
example:

BOOL areTheyDifferent; why there is no pointer in this declaration?

Comment: Others have pointed out that * indicated the variable is a pointer to an NSString. As a next step, it might help to get a good understanding of the terms scalar, pointer, stack and heap as the apply to a language like C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `*` character means "pointer" in the C world (which Objective-C lives in)

`someString` is a pointer to an `NSString` object.

In Objective-C, you rarely need to worry about that fact, since all objects are passed around as pointers. You simply treat that `someString` variable as if it was an instance of the `NSString` class.

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare a variable as holding an object itself; you can only declare it as holding a pointer to an object. `BOOL`s aren't objects, so it's fine to have a variable containing a `BOOL` instead of a pointer to one. The same goes for numeric types, structures such as `NSRange` and `NSRect`, etc.—anything that isn't an instance of an Objective-C class.

I'm not sure why NeXT/Apple added this restriction. If I remember correctly, it only exists in Apple's version of GCC; the GNUstep version does not have it. That is, the GNUstep version allows you to declare a variable holding an object (`NSString myString`). Having never used GNUstep myself, I don't know how useful such variables really are in practice.

Comment: One reason not to support inline/sack objects might be to support retain and release. Retaining a stack object, or an object embedded in another object/structure doesn't really make sense since it can't live independently of its container.

Answer (score 0):

It tells the compiler that this is a pointer to a NSString.

Answer (score -1):

'bool' is a built-in type in the compiler. For all primitive types that the compiler natively understands, making a pointer to such an object is not neccessary. 
For objective C classes, a pointer is always neccessary, due to the design of the language.

It's a bit hard to explain in a few lines...

Comment: `bool` is built-in (sort of—at least under C99, it's a macro wrapping the built-in type `_Bool`), but `BOOL` is not: `BOOL`, `YES`, and `NO` are all macros defined by the Objective-C headers.